# How can I display the downloading speed for streaming videos?

Tags: video, video-streaming

Just wondering how I could find the download speed and/or the bandwidth for a particular streaming video while it is streaming. Is there some sort of application of function where I could display this information while I watch a video? Maybe possibly something along the lines of how Youtube allows viewers to right click and show video info.

Answer (score 0):

Ctrl+Alt+Del > Start task manager > Performance tab > Resource Monitor (bottom of window) > Network tab > expand Processes with Network Activity

Comment: Oh wow, that's pretty sweet. Never knew about this function. Had something more specific to the video in mind though since I may have multiple videos on each window. It seems like this is the data being processed as a whole by my browser.

Comment: check the box next to your browser and drop down the Network Activity window. It will show all processes running in the browser. By analyzing the addresses you can see the stats for the video.